# Unable to cover Else part

Tags: apex, unit-test, case, code-coverage

I am writing a test class for custom case creation method. My controller code is given below:

```
public PageReference submitCase() {
        try{
            if(c.suppliedEmail == '' || c.suppliedEmail == null){
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'Email field cannot be left blank'));  
                return null;
            }
            else{
                c.status = 'New';
                c.origin = 'Web';
                INSERT C;
            }
```

And my test class code is given below:

```
@isTest(seeAllData =false)
public class WebToCaseCustomContollerTest{
        static testMethod void caseTestData(){
            Contact cntct = new Contact(lastName = 'Testcontact');
            insert cntct;
            WebToCaseCustomContoller webObj = new WebToCaseCustomContoller();
            webObj.submitCase();  }
}
```

I am unable to cover the else part here.
How to pass suppliedEmail field to my case so that I can cover my else part
How do I increase my test coverage?

Comment: setting value to `suppliedEmail` is depends on the accessibility of `c`. So need that code snippet as well. BTW, your objective should be to perform unit test and not just to cover the code

Comment: C is coming from the vf page like this:

public Case c { get; set; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
    WebToCaseCustomContoller webObj = new WebToCaseCustomContoller();
            webObj.c.suppliedEmail = 'fake@email.com';
webObj.submitCase();
```

Also if your Case not initialized you need to initialize that first:

```
Case c = new Case(Name='problem');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Learnt a new thing here.